# Adding a badge to the round button - Swift

Tags: swift, button, rounded-corners, badge

I would like to position the red dot below as the badge always to the top right of the button.

```
let badgeView = UIButton (frame: CGRect (x: 20, y: 40, width: 16, height: 16))
self.addsubview (badgeview)
```

With this code, the result is like this and is erroneous:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: sorry , I added the picture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use constraints to align a view to superview's top right. Add a badgeView to a `UIButton` like below. You can play with constants.

```
// your button
let buttonSize: CGFloat = 50
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: buttonSize, height: buttonSize))
button.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
button.layer.cornerRadius = buttonSize / 2

// your badge view (use UIView instead of UIButton)
let badgeSize: CGFloat = 16
let badgeView = UIView()
badgeView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 235/255, green: 68/255, blue: 90/255, alpha: 1)
badgeView.layer.cornerRadius = badgeSize / 2
button.addSubview(badgeView)

// set constraints
badgeView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
let constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [
    badgeView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.rightAnchor, constant: -4),
    badgeView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.topAnchor, constant: 0),
    badgeView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: badgeSize),
    badgeView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: badgeSize)
]
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the sizes of the badge and the button that the badge is on are both constant, the badge's frame should be:

```
CGRect(x: radius * cos45 + radius, y: radius - radius * cos45, width: 0, height: 0).insetBy(dx: -8, dy: -8)
```

where `cos45` is `sqrt(2) / 2` and `radius` is the radius of the black button. This will draw the badge with its centre on the circumference of the button.

```
let cos45 = sqrt(2) / 2
let badgeView = UIButton (frame: CGRect(x: radius * cos45 + radius, y: radius - radius * cos45, width: 0, height: 0).insetBy(dx: -8, dy: -8))
// make badgeView look pretty...
self.addSubview (badgeview)
```

I feel like using a `UIButton` for the badge is kind of weird, unless tapping the badge does something different from tapping the button. You could just use a regular `UIView` otherwise.